# Oracle/SQL - Combining records on keyfield

Tags: sql, oracle

imagine a table that looks like this

```
CUST    FLAG1   FLAG2
---------------------
1234    1       0
1234    1       1
1234    1       0
1234    0       1
5678    1       0
5678    1       0
9012    0       1
```

What I want to do is group by the cust field and combine the flags (which are boolean in nature) so I would get the following result

```
CUST    FLAG1   FLAG2
---------------------
1234    1       1
5678    1       0
9012    0       1
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that "combine the flags" means "OR the flags together" so that if any row has a 1 the end result has a 1, just do a `GROUP BY` with a `MAX`

```
SELECT cust,
       MAX(flag1) flag1, 
       MAX(flag2) flag2
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY cust
```

Comment: UGH - in a tizzy doing too many other things I over complicated this in my head.  Thanks; that was perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `SUM` and `SIGN`.

```
SQL> SELECT   cust
  2  ,        SIGN(SUM(flag1)) flag1
  3  ,        SIGN(SUM(flag2)) flag2
  4  FROM     t
  5  GROUP BY cust
  6  ORDER BY cust
  7  ;

CUST      FLAG1      FLAG2
---- ---------- ----------
1234          1          1
5678          1          0
9012          0          1
9999          0          0

SQL>
```